# SQL statement runs fine in TEST, breaks on PROD

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm executing the following query on my test DB, all works well:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME                    AS Name,
       (SELECT TOP 1 value
        FROM   Fn_listextendedproperty (NULL, 'schema', 'dbo', 'table', [TABLE_NAME], DEFAULT, NULL)
        WHERE  name = 'Description') AS [Description]
FROM   information_schema.tables tb
       INNER JOIN Fn_listextendedproperty (NULL, 'schema', 'dbo', 'table', DEFAULT, NULL, NULL) prop
               ON prop.objname COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = tb.TABLE_NAME COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
                  AND prop.name = 'SettingTable'
                  AND prop.value = '1'
ORDER  BY TABLE_NAME ASC
```

When executing on my production DB, I get the following error:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near 'TABLE_NAME'.
```

Test DB version: 10.50.1617.0

Prod DB version: 10.50.2550.0

Any ideas?

Comment: I tried the same query in my sql server 2008, it worked fine.

Comment: This also works on my 2008, and 2012 editions, and on [SQL Fiddle's 2008 R2 Version](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/40493).

Comment: @Arne Deruwe: What happens if you remove the `ORDER BY TABLE_NAME asc` part of the query?

Comment: Same problem without the order by

Comment: How is it without the square brackets around `[TABLE_NAME]` on line 3?

Comment: THe same :( that should prevent duplicate naming issues in the first place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the PROD DB was running in SQL server 2000 compatibility mode..
Setting this to 2008 resolved the issue, and my sanity. Thanks for the replies!